# How to handle Micro Popup in Webdriver.io browser

Tags: webdriver-io

When starting a website, I find it difficult to click Block button on Microphone popup because I can't query this popup (and also with block btn)

How can I handle this problem with Webdriver.io in browser?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVWL2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use chrome command line switches. You can find the list [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#use-fake-device-for-media-stream).

The one you are looking for is `use-fake-device-for-media-stream`. You can set this in your config file so that every time the chrome is launched, it won't show this popup since it is already set to a fake device.

Comment: Thank you. 
Right now, I use `deny-permission-prompts` in the list above and it works. However, the problem is that it deny all permissions including camera and microphone but I just want to deny microphone, allow camera. How can I do that ?